# Discord.py How can I get the content of a fields of a embed?

Tags: discord.py

I want to get all the content of the fields, but I get only "Embed.Empty", even if the embed contains fields. What can I do?

```
for emb in message.embeds:
        for field in emb.fields:
            print(field.title)
                print(field.description)
```

Comment: You have an indentation error.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.title` and `.description` in discord.Embed.fields, however, there is `.name` and `.value`. You may want to look through the documentation of Embeds: [discord.Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed)

```
for emb in message.embeds:
    for field in emb.fields:
        print(field.name)
        print(field.value)
```